# Bot Framework AutoFac Dependency Issue C# (Multiple Container)

Tags: c#, botframework, autofac, azure-language-understanding, autofac-configuration

In my app start I have the following code to register my module.

```
Conversation.UpdateContainer(builder =>
            {
                builder.RegisterModule<MyModule>();
            });
```

And I am using InstrumentedLUIS which has the following code.

```
   var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

   builder.Register(c => new BotFrameworkApplicationInsightsInstrumentation(CreateBasicSettings()))
            .Keyed<IBotFrameworkInstrumentation>(InstrumentationType.Basic)
            .SingleInstance();

   builder.Register(c => new BotFrameworkApplicationInsightsInstrumentation(CreateSettingsWithCognitiveServices()))
            .Keyed<IBotFrameworkInstrumentation>(InstrumentationType.Cognitive)
            .SingleInstance();

   _container = builder.Build();
```

Because of the above code my module register is getting lost and every subsequent call to bot I am getting, the requested service is not register please use optional.

Since I am not aware of the latest Autofac, can any one please guide me?

Comment: If you can provide a reproducible sample, which can help find and troubleshoot issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container)); after _container = builder.Build(); although this is only one step to solve your issue I recommend you to read this [per-request lifetime scope](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html?highlight=DependencyResolver#troubleshooting-per-request-dependencies)